# PHP cURL XML example sometimes returns blank, most of the time

Tags: php, xml, unix, curl

Here are my code samples:

```
function xmlPostStore($post_xml, $url, $port) {
    $ch = curl_init(); // initialize curl handle
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url to post to
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // Fail on errors
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port); //Set the port number
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); // times out after 15s
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_xml); // add POST fields
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

what i'm sending:

```
$XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
        <SendConfig>
            <Request>
                <key>passphrase</key>
            </Request>
        </SendConfig>";

$reply = xmlPostStore($XML, "http://www.urlhere.com/test.php", "80");
```

test.php is just a simple XML return:

```
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<response>
    <config>
        <test>it works</test>
    </config>
</response>";
```

When I test this on one server, it works 100% of the time. I receive a response and there's no issues.

When I test it on our main server, it returns back nothing, most of the time, about 98% of the time it's blank. Without any code changes, it will randomly work and randomly stop. I'm stumped.

Comment: "some times, most of the time, 98% of the time"?

Comment: well, where you are echoing `$reply` variable? It is storing the returned data!

Comment: @MarcB thats funny! but try to figure his problem out :D

Comment: I am echoing the $reply, which does say "it works" on one server. The other server still remains blank. I've even disabled both firewalls and it's still not working. Sorry I didn't add that last bit of code, but it is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what I believed to be opening the firewall to allow incoming and outgoing connections was only allowing incoming, not outgoing. I also resolved a DNS error under resolv.conf and things are now working correctly.